# Localhost redirect to different project folder

Tags: prestashop, local

I am working in a prestashop project.

*Operating System: Linux Mint 19.1*

*CMS: prestashop*

The problem came today, when I cloned my production site to my local machine.

It was not the first time I cloned this project. Actually, I have in:

```
/var/www/html
```

different directories:

```
pre_prestashop pre_magento etc
```

Now as I said, I copied from production real live website, to local machine in a new directory within /var/www/html

I called it:

**dev_prestashop**

Everything was perfect, and I can see when I type localhost in my browser every project/directory:

```
pre_prestashop 
pres_magento and 
=> dev_prestashop
```

The fact is, when I try to access `locahost/dev_prestashop` it makes a redirect to my old directory `localhost/pre_prestashop` (pre_prestashop works and local site is OK, but it is my OLD local site and not dev_prestashop).

I've been googling but none is experiencing this issue.

I check my `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and see:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html
     ServerName localhost
     ServerAlias pre_calleja
     ServerAlias dev_prestashop

     <Directory /var/www/html/>
          Options +FollowSymlinks
          AllowOverride All
     </Directory>

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I verified every single filed in database, and deleted `.htaccess` file from root directory in dev_prestashop...

I can't understand what is happening.

Actually, If I comment `pre_prestashop` to `_pre_prestashop` and change `dev_prestasho`p to `pre_prestashop`, everything works perfectly, so problems is not in dev_prestashop.

I would apreciate very much help to understand this problem, more than solve it because now I am working in renamed folder.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you updated `domain`, `domain_ssl` and `physical_uri` columns from `ps_shop_url` table?

Comment: hi @idnovate, yes, I do. Everything in bbdd is OK, I check 100 times :(
Even parameters.php data

Comment: Have you opened the store in a private tab?

Comment: @joseantgv yes, It is not chache. I have it desactivated

Comment: Have you removed /var/cache?

Comment: @joseantgv yes I do.